# Echoing into named pipe created by another user gives permission denied

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I first created a named pipe from a user

```
mkfifo -m 0777 /tmp/pipe
```

Then, from another user I tried to write to it, but it gives me error

```
echo 1 > /tmp/pipe
bash: /tmp/pipe: Permission denied
```

which should not happen, since I've set read-write permissions for all users earlier. I've also tried using chmod 777 but no luck.

Comment: see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/503111/group-permissions-for-root-not-working-in-tmp

Comment: simple fix: make a subdirectory inside `/tmp` and put the fifo inside that

Comment: why `0777` rather than `0666` ?

Answer (score 2):

In Unix-like systems, the `/tmp` folder is a **`sticky`** folder by default.

As mentioned here:

> the sticky bit is a user ownership access right flag that can be assigned to files and directories on Unix-like systems.

> For directories, when a directory's sticky bit is set, the filesystem treats the files in such directories in a special way so only the file's owner, the directory's owner, or root user can rename or delete the file

So, either make an other subdirectory under `/temp`.

Or remove that sticky bit:

```
sudo chmod -t /tmp
```

And then turn it back on afterward:

```
sudo chmod +t /tmp
```

Refer to this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687608/permission-denied-in-tmp#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=To%20anyone%20having%20the%20same,sudo%20chmod%20%2Dt%20%2Ftmp%20.) for more details.

**update:** note that removing the sticky bit  is not a good practice and it is not recommended to do it, thanks **@jhnc**

Comment: since `/tmp/pipe` does not have its sticky bit set, your `chmod` commands will do nothing useful. see my comments on the question

Comment: note the comment on the answer at your link which tells you that removing the sticky bit on /tmp is not a good solution (especially on a multiuser system where it creates a security hole) - just create a subdirectory

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/10353/what-is-the-sticky-bit-in-unix-file-systems-when-is-it-used

Comment: I'm just stating different  possible solution here. But, I totally agree with you. In fact, highlining that removing the sticky bit is a not recommended solution is certainly required.